# Asking Job Recruiter To Contact A Reference?

Tags: recruitment, recommendation-letter, recruiting

After asking a former professor about receiving a letter of recommendation, they told me they would write me a letter upon being requested.

Seeing that I have several references on my job application, how do I communicate this to employers? Should I just say something along the lines of "Please contact _ for a letter of recommendation"?

Comment: Letters of recommendation and references are typically considered and processed differently by recruiters. The applications you complete will typically have you fill in precisely who is expected to submit recommendations. Did you list your professor as a reference or as a recommender?

Comment: Do the others references know you've listed them?

Comment: Do you have account on Linkedin? Does you professor have account on Linkedin? Have you considered asking your professor about leaving a public recommendation to your profile on Linkedin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your professor has account on Linkedin, I would suggest to ask your professor to leave a public recommendation to your profile on the Linkedin. If you don't have one, you should definitely create one.

In such case potential recruiters wouldn't need to contact your professor since they would directly see his/her public reference.

Comment: I just looked at the professor's Linkedin profile, and there's no profile photo and very limited details on their profile. Do you think this would this detract from the merit, even subconsciously, of the recommendation in the eyes of recruiters?

Comment: No, I don't think so. If I were recruiter, I wouldn't have been detracted by that